# What is the most appropriate way to store password in Android?

Tags: android, database, performance, sqlite, android-intent

I am creating an password application. This application stores password which is of 4 digits. There are also addresses of 10 images which I need to store. So  I need to store only single password of 4 digits and addresses of 10 images.

In the application, user can change password and set of 10 images. I need to know the most efficient way to do this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a mechanism to store application data in **Shared Preferences**. But those are not encrypted.

**[scottyab](https://github.com/scottyab/secure-preferences)** has created one library which stores secure data in **Shared Preferences**.

> This is Android Shared preference wrapper that encrypts the keys and values of Shared Preferences using 256-bit AES. The key is stored in the perferences and so can be read and extracted by root user. Keys and values are encrypted and base64 encooded before storing into prefs.

[image]

**References**

- [secure-preferences](https://github.com/scottyab/secure-preferences)
- [SecurePreferences Demo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.securepreferences.sample)